# indexof - check if a value is already in array with javascript)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am working with angular and I am trying to create a "select all" button.

I have a list of items, each item has a toggle and what I am doing is, on change (everytime the toggle changes from true (selected) to false (not selected), I run a function to create an array with all the IDs of the selected elements.

This works almost perfectly, the problem is that I am facing some issues with the indexfOf method to check if the ID is already in the array.

```
var isInArray;

isInArray = function(arr, id) {
  console.log("index of ", arr.indexOf(id));
  return arr.indexOf(id);
};


scope.evtSelectAll = function() {
  return angular.forEach(scope.listToDisplay, function(element) {
    element.copyTo = true;
    return scope.selectFromList(element.iID, element.copyTo);
  });
};

scope.selectFromList = function(id, copy) {
  if (copy === true && isInArray(scope.selected, id) === -1) {
    scope.selected.push(id);
  } else {
    scope.selected.pop(id);
  }
  console.log("scope.selected - ", scope.selected);
  if (scope.selected.length > 0) {
    console.log("Emitted event: can proceed!");
    scope.$emit('enough-elements');
  } else {
    console.log("Emitted event: can not proceed!");
    scope.$emit('not-enough-elements');
  }
  return scope.result = scope.selected;
};
```

the problem I've got is when the array (scope.selected) has multiple IDs.

Let's say, for example, that my scope.selected looks like this:

```
scope.selected = [2,3,4,7]
```

if I click on select all, nothing gets added (and this is correct)

Now, let's say I untick 4 and 7 for example, and my scope.selected now looks like this:

```
scope.selected = [2,3]
```

If I now click on select all, my result is the following: [2,4,7].

I lose the **3**

I think this is due to the fact that my array doesn't have one single item?

thanks for any help. Here's also a quick [codepen](http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/KNXPBb?editors=0010) to explain the problem. If you check the console and play with the toggles you should be able to see straight away what I am referring to.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Would it be an issue to empty $scope.selected entirely and recreate it by reparsing the checked elements in the list, once a toggle has occured?

Comment: No I don't see why it should be an issue to be honest. I just need to be careful to empty it only on select all I guess, right?

Comment: at least in the codepen example, the `element.iID` should be changed to `element.id`

Comment: thanks, I corrected iID with id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to **Matthias** and **Christian Bonato** for their suggestions.

At the end, I solved using both of their suggestions and the final result seems to work as expected.

Here's a codepen with the final version: http://codepen.io/NickHG/pen/KNXPBb

Basically, I changed

```
scope.selected.pop(id);
```

with

```
$scope.selected.splice( isInArray($scope.selected, id),1);
```

and in the selectAll event function, I always empty `scope.selected[]` before adding elements to the array

```
$scope.evtSelectAll = function() {
$scope.selected = []
angular.forEach($scope.list, function(element) {
  element.copyTo = true;
  return $scope.selectFromList(element.id, element.copyTo);
});
```

};

thank you for your help!

Comment: emptying the array seems like a nice solution to the problem here, good work

Comment: I can accept only in two days. I will accept as soon as I can. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think mostly your code contains a logical error. You are using the function `selectFromList` to de-select (when done individually) and for the select all (which you don't want to use to de-select).

As someone pointed out in a for some reason now deleted answer, the [`pop.()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop) function shouldn't be called with any arguments (it is only for removing the last element), you should use splice like this:
`$scope.selected.splice( isInArray($scope.selected, id),1);`

Unless you really need the emitted functionality to run on a select all, you can try if this is the answer for you:

```
var isInArray;

isInArray = function(arr, id) {
  console.log("index of ", arr.indexOf(id));
  return arr.indexOf(id);
};


scope.evtSelectAll = function() {
  return angular.forEach(scope.listToDisplay, function(element) {
    element.copyTo = true;
    if (isInArray($scope.selected, element.id) === -1) {
      $scope.selected.push(element.id);
    }
  });
};

scope.selectFromList = function(id, copy) {
  if (copy === true && isInArray(scope.selected, id) === -1) {
    scope.selected.push(id);
  } else {
    $scope.selected.splice(isInArray($scope.selected, id), 1);
  }
  console.log("scope.selected - ", scope.selected);
  if (scope.selected.length > 0) {
    console.log("Emitted event: can proceed!");
    scope.$emit('enough-elements');
  } else {
    console.log("Emitted event: can not proceed!");
    scope.$emit('not-enough-elements');
  }
  return scope.result = scope.selected;
};
```

Now the select all only adds to `scope.selected` if it doesn't find the id in the `scope.selected` list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I added your line, and I changed the select all function to include the first comment (empty scope.selected when I click on select all) and with the two combined solution, it seam to work as I need. Thanks a lot